# Is DefaultModelBinder available for .net core mvc to encrypt and decrypt action parameters?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I want a customize modelbinder for .net core mvc action parameters, but I not sure DefaultModelBinder is available in .net core. this is .net standard example for customize modelbinder.

```
public class EncryptDataBinder : DefaultModelBinder
        {
            public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
            {
                object result = 0;
                if (bindingContext.ModelType == typeof(int))
                {
                    var valueProviderResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
                    if (valueProviderResult != null)
                    {
                     // decryption code                    
                    }
                }
            return base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
           }   
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ASP.NET Core, you need implements `IModelBinder`.

A simple demo below about custom model binder to change the bound Id:

Model

```
public class Author
{
    [ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(EncryptDataBinder))]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Custom IModelBinder

```
public class EncryptDataBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bindingContext));
        }
        
        if (bindingContext.ModelType == typeof(int))
        {
            // Try to fetch the value of the argument by name
            var valueProviderResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
            if (valueProviderResult != null)
            {
                int id = 3;
                //bind the new id....
                bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(id);
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
        }             
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Post([FromForm]Author model)
{
    return Ok(model);
}
```